# how to optimize the xml parsing to perform faster

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am trying to de-serialize huge XML to dynamic object in C#. Here is the below code snippet which was used for de-serialization.

have tried replacing both foreach loops in the below code snippet with **Parallel.ForEach** but the still it's taking more time to parse.

```
public dynamic Parse(XElement node)
    {
        IDictionary<String, dynamic> result = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (var gn in node.Elements())
        {
            bool isCollection = gn.HasElements && gn.Elements().Count() > 1 && gn.Elements().All(e => e.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == gn.Elements().First().Name.LocalName);
            List<XElement> items = isCollection ? gn.Elements().ToList() : new List<XElement>() { gn };
            List<dynamic> values = new List<dynamic>();

            items.ForEach(i => values.Add((i.HasElements) ? Parse(i) : i.Value.Trim()));
            result[gn.Name.LocalName] = isCollection ? values : values.FirstOrDefault();
        };

        return result;
    }
```

Currently the above code snippet is taking 6-8 seconds to deserialize 1000 xml files. Each XML which was tested is about 15KB Size.

But how can it be optimized further, and improve the performance even more better.

Comment: Maybe you could implement a threaded version, i.e. async?

Comment: Uhm, does this really do what you want? With a very simple test `<A><B><C>1</C></B><B><C>2</C></B></A>` I got *one* `B` with a `C` with the value of `2`. So you'll only ever get the last item of anything listlike. That seems weird. Also it completely ignores attributes. -- Wouldn't it be better to either have the structure of the XMLs as real classes and use real serialization/deserialization, or, if that's not possible, work directly with `XElements`, which is quite comfortable as it is.